# Conditional kinetic equations

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

From a biological system, I got the following reaction:

$$A+B+D\rightarrow C+C_1D$$ ($C_1D$ is a certain complex)

However, if at any given time there are no $D$s to react, and **only** then, instead the following reaction does happen (until a new $D$ appears, at which point the first reaction switches in instead):

$$A+B\rightarrow C+C_2$$

So, the second reaction happens if and only if there are no $D$s.

Therefore, this system is like a "conditional" system, where under existence of $D$ the first reaction happens, until all $D$s are used, and then . At any given time, more $D$s can appear and then the whole reaction system acts again as described above.

In the above system, what are the kinetic equations?

(Note: of course, this is not the complete reaction scheme, but the minimum one to extract equations for. However, it should be noted that I consider $[D]=g(t)$, i.e. not constant equal to the initial concentration of $D$. Of course $g(t)$ also depends on the aforementioned reactions too, but on others also)

Comment: Without a mechanism you can't get the rate equation (i.e. rate vs concentration of species). And the mechanism will be complicated because the way you set it up, reaction 2 is shut off completely as soon there is a little bit of D. That is very unusual.

Comment: You will only be able to solve these equations numerically if D varies in time externally to the scheme given, ie. as some arbitrary g(t). If you want exclusive reactions (or nearly so ) then the rate constant for reaction 1 should be vast compared to that for 2 such that when D is present  1 is favoured, but you will always have some of reaction 2.